# Method 'System.String GetState(int32)' has no supported translation to SQL

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, linq-to-entities, linq-to-objects

I'm using the below code to fetch the state. I'm getting the error" Method 'System.String GetState(int32)' has no supported translation to SQL".Please let me know where i'm doing a mistake.

```
    public IQueryable<ViewModel> GetResult()
            {
                IQueryable<ViewModel> result;

                if (isDestinationSite)
                {
                    result = (from table1 in this.db.tblTable1      
                              select new ViewModel
                              {
                                 State= this.GetState(table1.PersonUID),                                
                              });
                }

   private string GetState(int PersonUID)
        {
            using ( PersonPref pref = new PersonPref ())
            {
                pref .selectPref(ApplicationCode.MyApp,                                                  PersonPref .preference);
                if (pref.PesronValue== "True")
                {

                    return "Successfull";
                }
                else
                {
                    return "Failure";
                }
            }            
        }
```

Comment: Side note: surprising set of tags - error looks like coming from LINQ-to-SQL, but tags explicitly state otherwise... Consider editing.

Comment: The error message seems pretty self explanatory.  The LINQ query provider can't translate that method into SQL...

Answer (score 4):

SQL doesn't know anything about your function so you just need to move it outside of your linq query.

```
List<ViewModel> result;

var personUID = (from table1 in this.db.tblTable1 select table1.PersonUID).ToList();

foreach (var id in personUID)
{
    result.Add(new ViewModel { State = GetState(id) });
}
```

Comment: Good explanation/shows the idea for fix just fine. Please consider to edit `result.State = GetState(result.State);` into something that is close to valid C# - `result` is enumerable of {int State}, and does not really have `result.State`.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov yep i realized that as soon as i posted, i think it's good now let me know if i missed something

Comment: Looks ok. It may be good idea to add notice that you really can't get real `IQueryable` that way as one have to run query client side to convert to collection of `ViewModel`...

Comment: Side note: there are probably many similar questions already (search for http://www.bing.com/search?q=Method+has+no+supported+translation+to+SQL gives some) - so avoid spending too much time on this one :)

Answer (score 0):

You can write iterate your query with `AsEnumerable` and then do the selection like:

```
  result = (from table1 in this.db.tblTable1      
            .AsEnumerable()
              select new ViewModel
              {
                 State= this.GetState(table1.PersonUID),                                
              });
```